# Ctrl+F search field is separated between the tabs opened, is it normal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When searching for a string inside an opened file (with Ctrl+F3 for example or CTRL+F) if I change to another opened file (inside another tab) the search is not kept.

Is this behavious normal? Can I configure it to have the same search values across tabs?

Comment: I'm using 1.22.2 and search is kept between opened files.

Comment: I'm using 1.22.2 and it is not for me :/ Did you upgraded from an older version or installed from scratch ?

Comment: I upgraded from an older version.